# JLabel#setIcon in javafx

Tags: java, swing, javafx, jlabel

I have a Swing code base, which is using a lot of `new JLabel().setIcon()` like snippets.

I'm trying to migrate this app to JavaFX, but I have no idea on how to do that since there is no such method using the JavaFX `Label` object.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a label, not a text.

Comment: @James_D when using a label there is still no such method...

Comment: Well no but there's a `setGraphic` method.

Comment: Yes use a [Label](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Label.html) with `setGraphic` of a Node (like ImageView).

Comment: A thanks, thatd exactly what I needed!

Comment: @JoopEggen I think you can post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Label` with `setGraphic` of a `Node` (like `ImageView`). As @James_D commented.

As a JLabel you can also immediately add a "graphic" (image) to the constructor.

What is misleading is the different API terminology, and the abstract `Node` as child of the `Label`.